# Threadlist of TObject with Delphi - How to populate?

Tags: multithreading, list, delphi, object, tobject

From my limited knowledge about this subject, the following code should work. But I have not the expected result:

```
type
  TClient = class(TObject)
    Host: String;
  end;

var
  Clients: TThreadList;

const
  Hosts: Array[0..5] of String = ('HOST1', 'HOST2', 'HOST3', 'HOST4', 'HOST5', 'HOST6');
var
  I: Integer;
  List: TList;
  Client: TClient;
begin
  try
    for I := Low(Hosts) to High(Hosts) do
    begin
      Client := TClient.Create;
      with Client Do
      try
        Host := Hosts[I];
        List := Clients.LockList;
        try
          Clients.Add(Client);
        finally
          Clients.UnlockList;
        end;
      finally
        Client.Free;
      end;
    end;
  except
    on E:Exception Do ShowMessage(E.Message);
  end;

// RESULT TEST
List := Clients.LockList;
try
  I := List.Count;
  S := TClient(List.Items[0]).Host;
finally
  Clients.UnlockList;
end;
ShowMessage(IntToStr(I));
ShowMessage(S);
```

My expected result would be 6 and HOST1, but I got 1 and "" (empty)

Please, what I am missing?

Thanks!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
List := Clients.LockList;
try
  Clients.Add(Client); // <--- mistake here
finally
  Clients.UnlockList;
end;
```

The idiom is that you lock the list with a call to `LockList` and that returns a mutable list. So you need to call `Add` on `List`.

```
List := Clients.LockList;
try
  List.Add(Client);
finally
  Clients.UnlockList;
end;
```

That said, `TThreadList` does offer an `Add` method that internally uses `LockList`. The reason that your call to that `Add` was failing is that you have used the default value of `Duplicates` which is `dupIgnore`. And you were passing the same memory address each time.

Why was the memory address the same each time? Well, the other mistake you made was to destroy your `TClient` objects and refer to them later. I guess the memory manager was re-using the memory that you just deallocated.

You might want to set `Duplicates` to `dupAccept`. At the very least you need to be aware that it has a potential impact.

This program produces your desired output:

```
{$APPTYPE CONSOLE}

uses
  SysUtils, Classes;

type
  TClient = class(TObject)
    Host: String;
  end;

const
  Hosts: Array[0..5] of String = ('HOST1', 'HOST2', 'HOST3', 'HOST4', 
    'HOST5', 'HOST6');
var
  I: Integer;
  List: TList;
  Client: TClient;
  Clients: TThreadList;
begin
  Clients := TThreadList.Create;
  Clients.Duplicates := dupAccept;

  for I := Low(Hosts) to High(Hosts) do
  begin
    Client := TClient.Create;
    Client.Host := Hosts[I];
    List := Clients.LockList;
    try
      List.Add(Client);
    finally
      Clients.UnlockList;
    end;
  end;

  List := Clients.LockList;
  try
    Writeln(List.Count);
    Writeln(TClient(List.Items[0]).Host);
  finally
    Clients.UnlockList;
  end;
end.
```

Or the loop could be simplified even further:

```
for I := Low(Hosts) to High(Hosts) do
begin
  Client := TClient.Create;
  Client.Host := Hosts[I];
  Clients.Add(Client);
end;
```

I neglected to perform any deallocations for the sake of a simpler exposition. Obviously in real code you wouldn't leak the way this code does.

Personally I'm not a fan of this class. Not in this age of generics. You really should be looking at `TThreadList<T>`.

```
{$APPTYPE CONSOLE}

uses
  SysUtils, Classes, Generics.Collections;

type
  TClient = class
    Host: string;
    constructor Create(AHost: string);
  end;

constructor TClient.Create(AHost: string);
begin
  inherited Create;
  Host := AHost;
end;

const
  Hosts: array[0..5] of string = ('HOST1', 'HOST2', 'HOST3', 'HOST4',
    'HOST5', 'HOST6');

var
  Host: string;
  List: TList<TClient>;
  Clients: TThreadList<TClient>;

begin
  Clients := TThreadList<TClient>.Create;
  Clients.Duplicates := dupAccept;

  for Host in Hosts do
    Clients.Add(TClient.Create(Host));

  List := Clients.LockList;
  try
    Writeln(List.Count);
    Writeln(List.First.Host);
  finally
    Clients.UnlockList;
  end;
end.
```

Comment: Thank you @David Heffernan for this complete and well explained answer!